# Replace first occurrence of character in string, but only if first character

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im looking to replace the first "/" in a string and the following works. Python3

```
>>> u'/test/test.json'.replace('/', '', 1)
'test/test.json'
```

However I do sometimes come across the following strings, where a "/" character exists but not as the first character. I only ever want to remove that character if it appears as the first character and only the first occurrence also.

```
>>> u'test/test.json'.replace('/', '', 1)
'testtest.json'
```

So **test/test.json** should remain **test/test.json**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [lstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) method just for that:

> str.lstrip([chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. The chars
> argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.

```
'/test/test.json'.lstrip('/')
```

Ouput:

```
'test/test.json'
```

Comment: This is not correct. What about `"//test/test.json"`? Only the first `/` occurrence should be removed

Comment: It would also return `'test/test.json'`, how would that be a problem?

Comment: yes this is very elegant thanks. works perfectly. forgot about lstrip.

Comment: The user only wants to remove the very first occurrence, as specified in the question. Anyway, this method of course covers most cases and it's a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution (`s` is your string):

```
s = s[1:] if s[0] == '/' else s
```

For example:

```
s = 'test/test.json'
print(s[1:] if s[0] == '/' else s) # 'test/test.json'


s = '/test/test.json'
print(s[1:] if s[0] == '/' else s) # 'test/test.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple function, which takes a string and when the first character of it is a string, it will remove it and return a proper value. If there will be no slash at the beginning, it will return a given string.

```
def replace_slash(string):
    if string[0] == '/':
        return string[1:]
    else:
        return string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first desired character by writing a condition for that

```
path = u'/test/test.json'
path = path[1:] if (path[0]=='/') else path

print(path)
```

Thank you